# Struts2 Field Error key created by FileUploadInterceptor required

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I am using Struts2 - FileUploadInterceptor to handle content type and maximum size of the file being uploaded.

In  order to display error messages, `<s:fielderror/>` is displaying error message which is perfect.

I am working on a page which has multiple sections and i need to display error messages belonging only to that section, problem with `<s:fielderror/>` is that it displays all error messages and to solve this parameters are to be passed, like

```
<s:fielderror><s:param>firstName</s:param></s:fielderror>
```

I am not sure what is the error key created by FileUploadInterceptor for content type error and maximum size error, please help me in addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to do something like this:

```
<s:fielderror>[some reference to a content type error]</s:fielderror>
<s:fielderror>[some reference to a max size error]</s:fielderror>
```

so that you can render them separately/differently.

This is currently **not possible** since `<s:fielderror/>` only takes field names.
You cannot separate the multiple errors for one field in this way.

Additionally, looking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/FileUploadInterceptor.java.html) for the `acceptFile` method in the `FileUploadInterceptor`, the max size is checked first and an error is set if that check fails.  The code doesn't continue to check for the allowed types if the max size already failed.

```
  353           } else if (maximumSize != null && maximumSize < file.length()) {
  354               String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.file.too.large", new Object[]{inputName, filename, file.getName(), "" + file.length()}, locale);
  355               if (validation != null) {
  356                   validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
  357               }
  358   
  359               LOG.warn(errMsg);
  360           } else if ((!allowedTypesSet.isEmpty()) && (!containsItem(allowedTypesSet, contentType))) {
  361               String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed", new Object[]{inputName, filename, file.getName(), contentType}, locale);
  362               if (validation != null) {
  363                   validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
  364               }
  365   
  366               LOG.warn(errMsg);
  367           }
```

So you should only get one of these errors at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry if i have confused by my question, my query is what should be the key to get the specific error, from your code, what should be exact key code for `[some reference to a content type error]`

Comment: @PramodCA What I'm trying to tell you is that there is **no such key** for just the content type error or just the max size error.  Your only option is `<s:param>myFileFieldName</s:param>`

Comment: My fileName is pramod_resume.doc than i coded as `<s:param>pramod_resume.doc</s:param>`, even with this, error wasn't displayed.

Comment: @PramodCA not your file name but the **name of the file field**.  If your file field is `<s:file name="uploadFile" label="Please select a file to upload"></s:file>` then you would use `<s:fielderror><s:param>uploadFile</s:param></s:fielderror>`